# How to move the views from a XIB file to storyboards in a project in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am new to iOS programming and Xcode. I have a project which is working perfectly fine with 5 `viewControllers` and `XIB` file. I have to add many more features in it (like Google Maps, iAd Banner and others) so I am finding it difficult to manage it all. So I thought to use Storyboards in my project so that I can see more clearly as to what view is getting loaded after a certain action is performed. Now I have to move the views and the whole project into storyboards from the XIB files.

I copied the 'view object' from the XIB files to Storyboard and just change the class name to the respective ViewController classes in the identity inspector. But that doesn't work. What more changes need to be done for this?

I checked out a few tutorials available on YouTube, but it didn't help much.

Please let me know how this can be done. If possible please also give me any links to gain some knowledge which can help me achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more, i am listing basic steps you should do (it may vary from case to case):

- you can copy the view controllers from Xib and paste it to storyBoard , give the class name to these as to your ViewController classes. May be you need to connect again the objects and other connection in ViewController.
- the method we use to instantiate a controller in case of Xib i.e.:

  ```
  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  ```

  will not be used anymore. Now you need ro connect the controllers with segue connections in the way it should be. Then instead of above method you need to use method:

  ```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  ```

to instantiate view objects then handle it accordingly.

There will many other changes too based on your code but these are basic changes.

Comment: Okay.. But I have a question... I created a new project with Storyboard and a SingleView application.. in that I didn't this function **- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender**

How does a new application know that it has to load the view from storyboard?

Comment: When you create new app with storyboard it includes a field in plist file for storyBoard. The baseView Controller name and the view which is by default created in storyboard name will be same and it will create the baseView using storyboard. Till this point no need to use the segue method(as you choose single view with storyboard your app is designed to take care till this point).  After that to add any other View you need to use segue method.