# how to xib view controller push a storyboard view controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

I am developing an app, and in the process, I have to arrange view controllers process  like storyboard->xib->storyboard because i have to use xib due to AR SDK. Could any friendly guy tell me how to xib->storyboard? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601690/how-to-move-the-views-from-a-xib-file-to-storyboards-in-a-project-in-xcode

Comment: [how-to-push-storyboard-from-loginviewcontroller-which-is-an-xib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460656/how-to-push-storyboard-from-loginviewcontroller-which-is-an-xib)  Also maybe: [changing-view-from-xib-to-storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025822/changing-view-from-xib-to-storyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyViewController* *myViewController = 
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:NULL] 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myController"];
```

using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier or instantiateInitialViewController to get storyboard view controller and you can call transitionFromViewcontroller:toViewController:duration:option:animations:completion api to bring up the view or you can just present view.